# Ruby Rails "if" with condition of "false" actually executes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I really don't know what I am not seeing here, because it looks to me that "if false" is acting like "if true".  To make it clear, I actually took screenshots of my RubyMine 6.0.3 screens.  This one is probably simple, but it surely looks crazy to me...

The code is in DevicesController#update.  It has a breakpoint that occurs within an "if false" statement that shouldn't be executing.  See in this shot that I am on line 48 within the if:
[image]

The variable dump at this time follows, that shows that params[:device][:chg_pwd], the if condition, is false.
[image]

So, why am I within this if statement when its condition is false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"false"` is `true` in ruby. you want `== "true"`

In Ruby, only `nil` and `false` are false. For more, you can read this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362)

```
if params[:device][:chg_pwd] == "true"
```

Depending on your situation, the other options are

1. Set to `nil`, or `false`. Then your existing code would work.
2. Set to `""` and check with `blank?` as a previous version of RSB's answer
   used to say, this is Rails only though, and does involve a small
   semantic difference (blank vs false)

Comment: Oh, gawd.  That is so right.  I updated the edit view to use simple_form and it sets the variable.  I copied the code and now realize that it was setting a string not a Boolean as you say.  But, I want to set the Boolean in the view, and not "not" the string...  Too funny!

Comment: Looking at my code, I was actually attempting to set a Boolean and not a string.  But, I am new to simple_form.  I will figure out what is wrong.  The view code is, which looks right but must not be, is: <%= f.input :chg_pwd, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false, label: "Generate new password?" %>

Comment: @R_G am guessing all you can set it to is a string, atleast when receiving from the web browser. So your false is getting `to_s`ed to `"false"`

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean.  Your edit to test for string "true" makes good sense.  However, if you look a the code I posted in the comment above, it surely seems like it should return a Boolean and not a string...

Comment: @R_G when talking to browser everything happens in strings so your code -> html -> browser -> user -> server, all works with strings. So when you say `true` it will be converted to `"true"` at some stage there. I do not believe it is possible to get it to actually return `true` instead of `"true"`. Same with numbers `1` becomes `"1"`

Comment: Yes, I see that and agree.  Just saying that the code format makes it as clear as mud. Thanks...

Comment: @R_G ah ok. Yeah, just one of the gotchas in the field (unless i am terribly wrong and there is actually a way)

Answer (score 2):

It returns `"false"`, which is a `string`, so it returns `true`.

```
if params['is_admin'] == 'true'
# YOUR CODE goes HERE
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead of "false" as "false" is a string and not a boolean value in your code

```
if params[:devise][:chg_pwd].eql?("false")
  # code
else
  # code
end
```

This would explain it better

```
2.0.0p247 :012 > if "true"
2.0.0p247 :013?>   p "hello"
2.0.0p247 :014?>   end
"hello"
 => "hello" 
2.0.0p247 :015 > if "false"
2.0.0p247 :016?>   p "hi"
2.0.0p247 :017?>   end
"hi"
 => "hi"
```